# forcing viewDidLoad at all app launches

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've noticed that viewDidLoad of the viewController will not run if the app has been "minimized" in the iOS multitasking state, and then you re-open it. It defaults to the last view, with none of the initialization of viewDidLoad.

I'd be interested in making sure that some piece of code always runs whenever the app is launched. Now I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461624/problem-with-viewdidload-method) that perhaps the appDelegate is the place for this. Before I re-arrange my code to move things from viewDidLoad to the application delegate, I thought I'd check here first to make sure there isn't any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the UIApplicationDelegate methods.  You can be notified when the application resumes from background.

```
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use the viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated method ?

Answer (score 2):

I sense a little broken MVC here. `viewDidLoad` method is a place to setup view objects to display data initialized in controller's init methods or launch some asynchronous or delegated task which depends on IBOutlets and views being loaded.

Putting code, that app depends on without views being loaded, into method that is mostly for preparing view specific things - is not a good idea. You should definitely check out app delegate methods for this.

Also `viewDidLoad` will be called if the view was unloaded. Can you confirm that `viewDidUnload` was called when you minimized your app?

Comment: most of my viewDidLoad relates to organizing subviews and determining which one displays first. but if you minimize and then re-launch an app, this convenience of forcing the view that will always appear first is not possible within viewDidLoad. so that's my main issue. I have a simple NSLog in my viewDidUnload which prints to console if it is called; it is not called when I minimize (perhaps you have a better suggestion for confirming if viewDidUnload runs)

Comment: If your `viewDidUnload` does not run - it means that your view is not unloaded and `viewDidLoad` will NOT get called. `viewDidLoad` gets called only if controller's view is unloaded while it's not visible and the app receives memory warnings.